# Devextreme datagarid : default value of column cells when whith lookup

Tags: javascript, angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

i'am using **devextreme** **datagrid** under my **Angular 5** app.

My **datagrid** looks like this :

```
<dx-data-grid
    #positionsDataGrid
    id="positionsDataGrid"
    [dataSource]="positionsDataSource"
    keyExpr="id"
    [allowColumnReordering]="true"
    [showBorders]="true"
    loadPanel="false">

    <dxo-paging [enabled]="true"></dxo-paging>
    <dxo-editing
      mode="row"
      [allowUpdating]="true"
      [allowDeleting]="true"
      [allowAdding]="true">
    </dxo-editing>

    <dxi-column dataField="id" caption="ID" [allowEditing]="false" [visible]="false"></dxi-column>
    <dxi-column dataField="Cuid" caption="name" [allowEditing]="false"></dxi-column>

    <dxi-column
      dataField="storeName"
      caption="Boutique"
      [width]="400"
      [setCellValue]="preSelectShop">
      <dxo-lookup>
        <[dataSource]="shops">
        <displayExpr="storeName>
        <valueExpr="ID">>
      </dxo-lookup>
    </dxi-column>

  </dx-data-grid>
```

i'am loading **initial data** from a WS (under '**positionsDataSource**' var ) :

```
  [{
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'test',
    'storeName': 'ABBEVILLE',
  }]
```

the default values cells of the column "**storeName**" din't appear

(but when **EDIT** mode ; the values re-appear)

My purpose is how to make the default values appear.

**Suggestions?**

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/)?

Comment: Hi, I think your dxi-column's dataField should be your storeId and in your dx-lookup you could use [(value)]="data.value"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, it will work:

```
onInitNewRow: function (e) {
        e.data.test= 'ABBEVILLE';
      e.component.__addingStart = true;
    },
```